# wkhtmltopdf with javascript option --run-script

Tags: javascript, zsh, wkhtmltopdf

I tried generating a PDF from a simple HTML page but the javascript is not executed?
*wkhtmltopdf version: 0.12.6 (with patched qt)*

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello World</title>
         <style>
            body {background-color: powderblue;}
            h1   {color: blue;}
            p    {color: red;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p class="myParagraph">my paragraph</p>
        <script>

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

ZSH:

```
wkhtmltopdf \
--run-script "
    window.onload = function() {
        document.body.style.background = 'pink';
        document.getElementsByClassName('myParagraph')[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
" \
--javascript-delay 1000 \
programma.html \
programma.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, finally I got it working!

- Do NOT use a `javascript:()` wrapper for the `--run-script` option
  like I saw somewhere, just plain JS
- Do NOT use `window.onload()`
  apparently the code get's already executed *onload*, I found that out
  with the `--debug-javascript` option
- I even got it working with jQuery, but you need to escape the `\$` sign

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello World</title>
         <style>
            body{background-color:white;}
            h1  {color:blue;}
            p   {color:red;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p class="myParagraph">my paragraph</p>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Vanilla JS
            document.body.style.background='lime';
            // jQuery
            $(document.body).css('background','orange');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

ZSH:

```
wkhtmltopdf \
--debug-javascript \
--run-script "
    document.body.style.background='silver';
    document.getElementsByClassName('myParagraph')[0].style.display='none';
    \$(document.body).css('background','gold');
" \
programma.html \
programma.pdf
```

**Bonus:**
When printing `navigator.appName`, `navigator.appVersion`, `navigator.appCodeName`

Result:
`Netscape`, `v5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Qt/4.8.7 Safari/534.34`, `Mozilla`